# Cannot set property error in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so i have this code that checks for dates and updates  lists accordingly, now what i am trying to achieve is that when the  for both the month and the year are set to null "mm" "yyyy" is set the day select list with one element "dd" with a value of null. but i have been having an error cannot set property 'value' of undefined. The first element in both the year and month s is set to a value of null.

this is the javascript function a guy here helped me come up with:

```
function monthDays (type) {

    if(document.getElementById('monthof' + type).value == null || document.getElementById('yearof' + type).value == null)
    {
        var mod = document.getElementById('dayof' + type);
        mod.length = 1;
        mod[0].value = null;
        mod[0].text = "DD";

    }
    else{
        var month = parseInt(document.getElementById('monthof' + type).value, 10),
            days = new Date(document.getElementById('yearof' + type).value, month + 1, 0).getDate(),
            i;
        var mod = document.getElementById('dayof' + type);

        mod.length = days + 1;
        mod[0].value = null;//this is where i am getting the error
        mod[0].text = "DD";
        for(i = 1; i < days+1; i++) {
            mod[i].value = i;
            mod[i].text = i;
        }
    }
}
```

html
    Birth: 
    
        MM

```
<select id="dayofbirth" class="date" name="dayhofbirth">
         <option value=null>DD</option>
</select>
<select id="monthofbirth" class="year" name="monthofbirth" onchange="monthDays('birth')">
    <option value=null>MM</option>
</select>
<select id="yearofbirth" class="year" name="monthofbirth" onchange="monthDays('birth')">
    <option value=null>YYYY</option>
</select>
</div>
```

the type is there to tell the function which  it should edit, since in my html I have 2 date of births.

Comment: You dont have anything with id `monthofbirth`

Comment: that a typo it is there in the actual code

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by `getElementById( )` returns a reference to an element, not an array of options when you're selecting a `select` element.  You can access the options through a property on the object but you don't need to do that to set the selected option.  To set the selected option, just set the value like you are but remove the `[0]` part.  You also need to set `null` as a string (`'null'`) because it is a string value in the HTML.

Here's what I came up with for you:

**HTML**

```
<select id="dayofbirth" class="date" name="dayhofbirth">
    <option value=null>DD</option>
    <option value=01>01</option>
</select>
<select id="monthofbirth" class="year" name="monthofbirth" onchange="monthDays('birth')">
    <option value=null>MM</option>
    <option value=12>12</option>
</select>
<select id="yearofbirth" class="year" name="monthofbirth" onchange="monthDays('birth')">
    <option value=null>YYYY</option>
    <option value=1900>1900</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function monthDays(type) {
    if(document.getElementById('monthof' + type).value == null || document.getElementById('yearof' + type).value == null)
    {
        var mod = document.getElementById('dayof' + type);
        mod.length = 1;
        mod.value = 'null';
    }
    else{
        var month = parseInt(document.getElementById('monthof' + type).value, 10),
            days = new Date(document.getElementById('yearof' + type).value, month + 1, 0).getDate(),
            i;
        var mod = document.getElementById('dayof' + type);

        mod.value = 'null';
        for(i = 1; i < days+1; i++) {
            mod.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/CT54h/

It probably doesn't do *everything* you want it to, but within the scope of the question it does.

Comment: I not fully get the scope of the .add since it does not set values, although I do appreciate your effort in order to help me out :)

Comment: When you call the `.add( )` method it doesn't specify a value as you noted, but by default the value is the contents of the option tag which is technically what you're doing in your example. To learn more about the `.add( )` method, go here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I had to do, I set the values at the beginning of each  to 'null' not null, and than when I checked for their value I also checked for 'null'. I think there might be some concept that I do not fully understand when it comes to  but my method seemed to have solved my problem.